# Is it possible to change my existing code for different parameter list

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, parameter-passing

The given below code is working fine. Here, I am doing parallelisation and I have also used `param_grid`, `ParameterSampler`.

```
def analyse(
    generate_dataset: Any,
    regressor: Any,
    method: Method,
    test_size: Tuple[float, float],
    k: int,
    n_reps: int,
    param_iters: int = 2,
) -> DataFrame:
    args = dict(
        generate_dataset=generate_dataset,
        regressor=regressor,
        method=method,
        test_size=test_size,
        k=k,
        n_reps=n_reps,
        param_iters=param_iters
    )

    param_grid = { "test_size": np.random.uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1], param_iters)  }
    sampler = list(ParameterSampler(param_grid, n_iter=param_iters))

    args = [Namespace(**{**args, **dict(params=params)}) for params in sampler]
   
    rows, _ = list(
        zip(*process_map(inner_loop, args, total=len(args), desc=f"Computing ECs for method '{method}'"))
    )

    df: DataFrame = pd.concat(rows, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

Now, I do not want to use `param_grid` and `ParameterSampler`. Instead, I want pass `args` without these two (`param_grid` and `ParameterSampler`). Though, I am not sure my idea will work or not.

Any idea to pass the args without `param_grid` and `ParameterSampler`?

Comment: `args` depends entirely on `sampler`, and consequently `param_grid` and `ParameterSampler`. What do you want `args` to hold if not data from those sources?

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you. I want to pass `generate_dataset, regressor, method, k, n_reps` is comming through the `def analyse()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure but can give you some idea about changing. Based on the idea you need to change more in your code.

1. Use `repeat` from `itertools`.
2. Change `n_reps` to `repetitions`.
3. Remove `args = dict()` and
4. Change `args` code to

```
   args = Namespace(
        **dict(generate_dataset=generate_dataset, regressor=regressor, reg_name=reg_name, method=method, k=k, repetitions=repetitions)
        )
```

5. Change `rows, _` to

```
    rows, _ = list(
        zip(
            *process_map(
                inner_loop,
                repeat(args, repetitions),
                total=repetitions,
                desc=f"Computing ECs for method '{method}'",
            )
        )
    )
```

You need to remove `param_iters`, `params`, and `test_size` everywhere you used in the program. Otherwise, you will get errors!

Comment: Thanks, this works. Yes, I had to change a lot of places but the idea worked.